# what is the theory of "plugin" in php scripts

Tags: php

All of us know what is the meaning of "plugin". We can see the wordpress you can add new job to your blog , just upload new php file.

I wondering what i have to do in my cms to make its system accept new jobs via php files or in other hand how i can make my cms **"plugin"** able (this mean i want to know the idea or the theory of the external and internal plugin)

my thinking we using [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function

Comment: found similar question:  (1). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217659/build-a-plugin-system-with-php (2). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315289/plugin-architecture-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your CMS, you can accomplish this.  Using [boot strapping](http://devzone.zend.com/400/blueprint-for-php-applications_bootstrapping-part-1/), you can filter all requests to your site to a single PHP file (aka 'The Boot Strap') which inspects what resource is being requested and attempts to handle that request.

Using the `file_exists` function you can determine if an appropriate handler is present and then `include`/`require` it if it does, instantiate a class, or however your CMS handles requests.

Without knowing more details about what CMS you are using, it is too difficult to come up with a more precise answer.

Comment: This answer would more correctly be termed an example of the [**"front controller pattern"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) than *"bootstrapping"*. A bootstrap file will simply provide everything the application needs to get started. The bootstrap file may implement the **front controller pattern**, but routing requests to an appropriate controller does not necessarily have anything to do with bootstrapping. Semantics, I know, but it seems the article referenced in the answer is also indulging this misconception.